# Jquery UI disable dynamic tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My UI tabs can change based on user action (example - a status message may appear in tab[0]).

I also need to be able to disable specific tabs - I know the href, but the index may well change.

The UI dox say that you can pass a href instead of an index, but I can't seem to get that to fly.

This is what I am doing instead:

```
var disableSlots = [];
$('ul.ui-tabs-nav li').each(function(index, el){
    if ($(this).children('a').attr('href') == '#DISABLE_ME'){
        disableSlots.push(index);
    }
});
$('#tabs').tabs("option","disabled",disableSlots);
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this approach:

```
var index = $('#tabs a[href="#DISABLE_ME"]').parent().index();
$('#tabs').tabs("option", "disabled", index);
```